# EF Update Exception: The conversion of a datetim2 data type to a datetime

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, linq-to-xml

I'm parsing some small XML files into EF objects, then loading them into a SQL Server 2008 database.

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Events](
    [ID] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED NOT NULL,
    [EventDate] datetime NULL
)
```

XML:

```
<root>
    <event date="2012-02-16T13:14:53" />
    <event date="2012-02-16T13:14:53" />
    <event date="2012-02-15T18:48:32" />
<root>
```

Parsing the XML:

```
var events = XDocument.Load(xmlStream)
    .Descendants("event")
    .Select(x => new Event
    {
        EventDate = (DateTime?)x.Attribute("date")
    });
```

Pushing to DB:

```
foreach(var event in events)
{
    dbContext.Events.Add(event);
}
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

And I get the following error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

I've searched around and tried all of the following to no avail:

- Changing the EDMX 'ProviderManifestToken' from "2008" to "2005"
- Changing the 'StoreGeneratedPattern' to "Computed"
- Altering the Linq to XML expression

Nothing seems to be working... running out of ideas here...

Comment: Sounds like the cast is failing. Though it looks like a standard format, verify that you are getting a correctly-casted date back. Otherwise, look in to using `if (DateTime.TryParse(..)){ EventDate = parsedDate; } else { EventDate = null; }`

Comment: Have you debugged?  What is the value of `EventDate` when you try to add it to the context?

Answer (score 1):

The solution had nothing to do with parsing that particular DateTime. I forgot I had a datetime column in the db that used a DEFAULT constraint. Once I took care of this, everything was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If I were parsing a DateTime from an XML string, I would try to use `DateTime.Parse`

It looks like that your datetime can be made parsable with a simple `String.replace`.

I thought there was a parse function that you could pass a formatting string to(like `"yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss"`), but I can't seem to find the documentation right now.

Comment: @ErOx  I didn't actually post a code sample.  What exactly did you try?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned try parsing the date directly.

```
EventDate = DateTime.ParseExact(x.Attribute("date"), "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss", Culture.InvariantCulture)
```

This type of errors usually appear when trying to insert DateTime.MinValue or DateTime.MaxValue to sql. Which is not a good idea. Can you print out events?

```
events.ForEach( x => Console.WriteLine(x.EventDate) )
```